# NPE causing crash using Android marketingcloudsdk 5.3.+

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, android, mobilepush-android

Facing this kind of crash while using MC 5.3.+

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.unparcel()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)


Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.unparcel()' on a null object reference
   at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:182)
   at android.content.Intent.putExtras(Intent.java:6347)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCService.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2579)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Does anyone has an idea of workaround, or if this is already mapped as a bug on future deployments?

Comment: Were you doing anything specific when this crash happened? Are there any steps to reproduce it?

Comment: Where is the "caused by" portion of the stacktrace?  Do you have any other logs available from the SDK?  Also, OS version of the device?  Was this for v5.3.0 or v5.3.1, 2, etc.

Comment: I got this on Fabric crashlytics, the rate is very low, and for version I've put this: compile ('com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.3.+')

About what I'm doing with the code, basically I just setup the sdk...